# version support policy for BYOD devices

Tags: android

In corporate environments where users bring their own devices for access to corporate resources, how can we determine which Android devices are currently supported and receiving security updates?

For iPhones and iPads this is fairly easy because Apple has only declared support for the most two recent versions of iOS.

Comment: Android's end of life for different versions is a bit hazy.  They constantly backport new functionality to older versions via support libraries.  I think you'd have to base this on the manufacturer/model of phone.

Comment: 2 Wifi spots: 1 for leasure/personnal. The other for work. For the first, where the Android/iOS devices come in I think you just should let it go. The other one, it's another issue entirely to me.